# how to generalize greatest-n-per-group within Spring Boot Data Jpa repositories

Tags: spring-data-jpa, greatest-n-per-group

In the context of a project using spring boot jpa with a lot of "historized" data, I would like to generalize the greatest-n-per-group to get particular data in time range (like the most recent at a given date).

Historical entities implement a special interface with a date range contract (getStartDate() and getEndDate()).

I know how to handle manually this kind of queries (the [greatest-n-per-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem), either with the query generator or with @Query, but but what if I want to generalize this to avoid repeating over and over the same piece of code in my repo ?